# Donde alojar archivos en proyecto web maven

Tags: java, web, eclipse, archivo, maven

Tengo un proyecto web construido con maven y eclipse que a partir de un arreglo de bytes debo escribir los archivos dentro de las carpetas del proyecto para luego a traves de una url se puedan descargar los archivos. Buscando lei que los archivos los podia dejar en la carpeta de `resources`. Efectivamente si coloco el archivo allí lo puedo descargar con la url `http://host:port/contextroot/nombre_archivo.ext` pero quiero que el path de descarga sea `http://host:port/contextroot/carpeta1/carpeta2/carpeta3/nombre_archivo.ext`, para ello cree dentro del proyecto en la carpeta `resources` esa estructura pero cuando busco el archivo en la segunda url aparece `not found` y si me lo muestra en la primera url.

Los archivos si los debo colocar en esa carpeta o como puedo hacer para que se descarguen con la segunda url.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

después de una buena trasnochada buscando como solucionar mi inquietud, la respuesta era mucho más sencilla de lo esperado y dice así:
**Es diferente la ruta física donde guardas los archivos y la URL con el que se desean descargar**. A continuación un resumen de lo que se realizó

1. A través del ServletContext injectado en la petición obtengo el RealPath("/") de la aplicación. A partir de alli se concatenaran las diferentes carpetas donde se desea guardar los archivos ej: `String rutaFisica = this.context.getRealPath("/") + "/recursos/archivos/"` si el directorio no existe se debe crear.

En mi caso los archivos quedaran almacenados en la ruta `C:\appsvr\jboss-eap-7.1\standalone\deployments\NombreProyecto.war\recursos\archivos\`

2. Ahora para poder descargarlo creamos un servicio web donde los `Path` conformaran la url para acceder al archivo

   `@Path("/descargas")
   public class DescargaService {
     @Path("/archivos/{nombreArchivo}")
     @GET
     @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
     public Response descargarArchivo(@Context ServletContext context, @PathParam("nombreArchivo") String archivo) {
       String pathfile = context.getRealPath("/") + "/recursos/archivos/" + archivo;
       File file = new File(pathfile);
       if(file.exists()) {
         ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) file);
         response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + archivo);
         return response.build();
       }else {
         return Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
       }
     }
   }`

De esta forma la url para descargar el archivo sería `http://host:port/contextroot/url-pattern/descargas/archivos/nombrearchivo`, es de aclarar que el `contextroot` es la mayoria de casos es el nombre de la aplicación y el `url-pattern` es la configuración del `servletMapping` del `web.config`